# could an apex class somehow open a window with a specific record of my org?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, record

I come with an interesting question, which I still can't find a solution.

We have installed an app called Talkdesk to our org sandbox. Basically, it is an app that works as a callcenter and has a feature of integrations that works as automated tasks.

[image]

You can apply external flows to the integrations from your org but only autolauched types.

For example, if at the end of the call, the disposition entered by the agent is "Interested", then it opens the person account associated to that phone number (if it exists in the org). When set as enabled, this feature opens the person account in the org, so far so good.

The problem is that instead of person account, I need it to open the associated Census Member to that person account.

My first thought was to create a screenflow to open the associated census member, but Talkdesk does not support it.

to be able to integrate new flows to Talkdesk, these must be autolaunched only.

[image]

So the question is, is there any way to open an org record with an apex class?

My idea would be to add an action to an autolaunched flow and this action would call that apex class that would have a method to open the census member record.

It can be done?

Is there any other way to open the record without using a screenflow, knowing that im very limited with the resources that talkdesk gives me?

Thanks in advance for the answers!!

Comment: If you implement a flow of vf page taht can be possible

Comment: I dont think it will work @CloudConnect, I need to open the record with an autolaunched flow. For what I know, I can embed a flow into a visualforce page but not the other way